# Unit testing Armeria's decorator using context.log().whenComplete()

Tags: armeria

I have a subclass of `SimpleDecoratingHttpService` that contains something like this:

```kotlin
    override fun serve(ctx: ServiceRequestContext, req: HttpRequest): HttpResponse {
        ctx.log().whenComplete().thenAccept {
            if (it.responseCause() == ...) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
        return unwrap().serve(ctx, req)
    }
```

I want to test the logic inside the `whenComplete()` callback. However, when writing tests like this:

```kotlin
myDecorator.serve(context, request).aggregate().join()
```

the `log()` future never completes. What do I need to do to ensure that the `log()` future eventually completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Emulating `RequestLog` completion

A `RequestLog` is completed by Armeria's networking layer, so just consuming an `HttpRequest` or `HttpResponse` will not complete a `RequestLog`. To complete it, you need to call the methods in `RequestLogBuilder`:

```java
var myDecorator = new MySimpleDecoratingHttpService(...);

var ctx = ServiceRequestContext.of(
    HttpRequest.of(HttpMethod.GET, "/hello"));
var req = ctx.request();

var res = myDecorator.serve(ctx, ctx.req).aggregate().join();

// Fill the log.
ctx.logBuilder().endRequest();
assert ctx.log().isRequestComplete();

ctx.logBuilder().responseHeaders(ResponseHeaders.of(200));
ctx.logBuilder().endResponse();

assert ctx.log().isComplete();
```

Armeria team uses the same technique for testing `BraveService`, so you might want to check it out as well at [BraveServiceTest.java:161](https://github.com/line/armeria/blob/d56d68e48ebd0f64094bd9bab4bcf576a1b4cd37/brave/src/test/java/com/linecorp/armeria/server/brave/BraveServiceTest.java#L161).

#### Testing with a real server

If your setup is too complex to use a mock, as an alternative approach, you can launch a real Armeria server so that Armeria fills the log for you. You can easily launch a server using `ServerRule` (JUnit 4) or `ServerExtension` (JUnit 5):

```java
class MyJUnit5Test {
  static final var serviceContexts =
      new LinkedBlockingQueue<ServiceRequestContext>();

  @RegisterExtension
  static final var server = new ServerExtension() {
    @Override
    protected void configure(ServerBuilder sb) throws Exception {
      sb.service("/hello", (ctx, req) -> HttpResponse.of(200));
      sb.decorator(delegate -> new MySimpleDecoratingHttpService(delegate, ...));

      // Record the ServiceRequestContext of each request.
      sb.decorator((delegate, ctx, req) -> {
        serviceContexts.add(ctx);
        return delegate.serve(ctx, req);
      });
    }
  };

  @BeforeEach
  void clearServiceContexts() {
    serviceContexts.clear();
  }

  @Test
  void test() {
    // Send a real request.
    var client = WebClient.of(server.httpUri());
    var res = client.get("/hello").aggregate().join();

    // Get the ServiceRequestContext and its log.
    var ctx = serviceContexts.take();
    var log = sctx.log().whenComplete().join();

    // .. check `log` here ..
    assertEquals(200, log.responseHeaders().status().code());
  }
}
```